# Update TortoiseSVN on Windows

Tags: svn, windows-installer, tortoisesvn

I tried to update *TortoiseSVN* on *Windows 7* x64. Currently installed version is (filename of installer) `TortoiseSVN-1.8.4.25041-dev-x64-svn-1.8.5.msi`. Recent version to update is `TortoiseSVN-1.9.3.27038-x64-svn-1.9.3.msi`. The later installer requires the former one to properly uninstall *TortoiseSVN* prior to installation of the new version. But I have no that old file. What to do?

Currently I tried to remove *Program Files* folder of TortoiseSVN, but it was an unsuccessfull attempt. Fresh installer still requires old one. I don't know what registry branches to edit to achieve the desired.

[Nightly builds available for now](https://nightlybuilds.tortoisesvn.net/1.9.x/x64/full/) are of `1.9.x` version only.

Comment: Normally, it does not require an older installer at all. You are looking for a wrong solution. You should describe the problem you have in detail.

Comment: BTW, try "Program Install and Uninstall" troubleshooter (you can get it at
http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall). Run the tool follow steps of the troubleshooting wizard. Does it help?

Comment: @bahrep Thank you for the advice, I'll try it in the evening.

Comment: @bahrep Thank you. It helps.